# Resolve circular dependency of type definitions

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Following a [C tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c1.aspx), I've encountered a type dependency that I don't know how to resolve. So far, we had this:

```
typedef long SetStringPtr( char * );
typedef long GetStringPtr( char *, long );

typedef struct {
    SetStringPtr * SetString;
    GetStringPtr * GetString;
} IExampleVtbl;

typedef struct {
    const IExampleVtbl * lpVtbl;
    DWORD count;
    char  buffer[80];
} IExample;
```

No problem. Now, it's changing to include a THIS pointer:

```
typedef long SetStringPtr( IExample *, char * );
typedef long GetStringPtr( IExample *, char *, long );

typedef struct {
    SetStringPtr * SetString;
    GetStringPtr * GetString;
} IExampleVtbl;

typedef struct {
    const IExampleVtbl * lpVtbl;
    DWORD count;
    char  buffer[80];
} IExample;
```

The definitions depend on each other in a circular way. The `cl.exe` compiler shows lots of syntax errors because by the time I use `IExample` it hasn't been declared yet. How can I resolve this?

Compile with `cl.exe /W4`.

**Update**

Thanks - three moreless equivalent answers at the same time, I could have chosen any one of them.

So, to resume, what choices do you have to make when solving this problem? First, naming convention - append `_t` to `typedef`s, or `_s` (or `Struct`) to `struct`s? Probably a matter of taste. Then, whether you want to have the forward definition as part of a `typedef` or as part of a `struct`. Probably also a matter of taste. Here's the problem in another form and three ways to solve it:

```
/* won't compile */
typedef struct {
        B * b;
        C * c;
} A;

typedef struct {
        A * a;
        C * c;
} B;

typedef struct {
        A * a;
        B * b;
} C;
```

First solution:

```
struct B_s;
struct C_s;

typedef struct {
        struct B_s * b; // typedef not available yet
        struct C_s * c; // ditto
} A;

typedef struct {
        A * a;
        struct C_s * c; // ditto
} B;

typedef struct {
        A * a;
        B * b;
} C;
```

Second solution:

```
typedef struct B_s B;
typedef struct C_s C;

typedef struct {
        B * b;
        C * c;
} A;

// typedef struct ... B => change to:
struct {
        A * a;
        C * c;
} B_s;

// typedef struct ... C => change to:
struct {
        A * a;
        B * b;
} C_s;
```

And the third (and most symmetrical) solution:

```
struct A_s;
struct B_s;
struct C_s;

typedef struct A_s A;
typedef struct B_s B;
typedef struct C_s C;

struct {
        B * b;
        C * c;
} A_s;

struct {
        A * a;
        C * c;
} B_s;

struct {
        A * a;
        B * b;
} C_s;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct IExample_s IExample;

typedef long SetStringPtr( IExample *, char * );
typedef long GetStringPtr( IExample *, char *, long );

typedef struct {
    SetStringPtr * SetString;
    GetStringPtr * GetString;
} IExampleVtbl;

struct IExample_s {
    const IExampleVtbl * lpVtbl;
    DWORD count;
    char  buffer[80];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Forward-declare:

```
struct IExampleStruct;   /* <--- !! */

typedef long SetStringPtr( struct IExampleStruct *, char * );
typedef long GetStringPtr( struct IExampleStruct *, char *, long );

/* ... */

typedef struct IExampleStruct {
    const IExampleVtbl * lpVtbl;
    DWORD count;
    char  buffer[80];
} IExample;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward declare the `IExample` struct.

```
//Forward Declare here
typedef struct IExample IExample_t;

typedef long SetStringPtr( IExample_t *, char * );
typedef long GetStringPtr( IExample_t *, char *, long );

typedef struct {
    SetStringPtr * SetString;
    GetStringPtr * GetString;
} IExampleVtbl;

struct IExample {
    const IExampleVtbl * lpVtbl;
    DWORD count;
    char  buffer[80];
};
```